# Converting PCRE recursive regex pattern to .NET balancing groups definition

Tags: .net, regex, pcre, recursive-regex, balancing-groups

PCRE has a feature called recursive pattern, which can be used to match nested subgroups. For example, consider the "grammar"

```
Q -> \w | '[' A ';' Q* ','? Q* ']' | '<' A '>'
A -> (Q | ',')*
// to match ^A$.
```

It can be done in PCRE with the pattern

```
^((?:,|(\w|\[(?1);(?2)*,?(?2)*\]|<(?1)>))*)$
```

(Example test case: http://www.ideone.com/L4lHE)

#### Should match:

`abcdefg` `abc,def,ghi` `abc,,,def` `,,,,,,` `[abc;]` `[a,bc;]` `sss[abc;d]` `as[abc;d,e]` `[abc;d,e][fgh;j,k]`
`<abc>` `[<a>b;<c,d>,<e,f>]` `<a,b,c>` `<a,bb,c>` `<,,,>` `<>` `<><>` `<>,<>` `a<<<<>>><a>>` `<<<<<>>>><><<<>>>>`
`<z>[a;b]` `<z[a;b]>` `[[;];]` `[,;,]` `[;[;]]` `[<[;]>;<[;][;,<[;,]>]>]`

#### Should not match:

`<a` `bc>` `<abc<de>` `[a<b;c>;d,e]` `[a]` `<<<<<>>>><><<<>>>>>` `<<<<<>>>><><<<>>>` `[abc;def;]` `[[;],]` `[;,,]` `[abc;d,e,f]`
`[<[;]>;<[;][;,<[;,]>]]>` `<z[a;b>]`

There is no recursive pattern in .NET. Instead, it provides [balancing groups](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/balancing-groups) for stack-based manipulation for matching simple nested patterns.

Is it possible to convert the above PCRE pattern into .NET Regex style?

<sub>(Yes I know it's better not to use regex in for this. It's just a theoretical question.)</sub>

#### References

- [pcre.org - PCRE man page - Recursive Patterns](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt)
- [MSDN - Regular Expression Language Elements - Balancing Group Definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition)

Comment: Nice question. My guess would be "no", but I'd love to see if someone comes up with a way to do it.

Comment: I think Perl is winning this battle. I might give it a shot at the evening, but it's too much for work :P

Answer (score 13):

The .Net alternative to recursive pattern is a stack. The challenge here is that we need to express the grammar it terms of stacks.
Here's one way of doing that:

### A slightly different notation for grammars

- First, we need grammar rules (like `A` and `Q` in the question).
- We have one stack. The stack can only contain rules.
- At each step we pop the current state from the stack, match what we need to match, and push further rules into the stack. When we're done with a state we don't push anything and get back to the previous state.

This notation is somewhere between [CFG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) and [Pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton), where we push rules to the stack.

#### Example:

Let's start with a simple example: a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup>. The usual grammar for this language is:

```
S -> aSb | ε
```

We can rephrase that to fit the notation:

```
# Start with <push S>
<pop S> -> "a" <push B> <push S> | ε
<pop B> -> "b"
```

In words:

- We start with `S` in the stack.
- When we pop `S` from the stack we can either:

  - Match nothing, or...
  - match "a", but then we have to push the state `B` to the stack. This is a promise we will match "b". Next we also push `S` so we can keep matching "a"s if we want to.
- When we've matched enough "a"s we start popping `B`s from the stack, and match a "b" for each one.
- When this is done, we've matched an even number of "a"'s and "b"s.

or, more loosely:

> When we're in case S, match "a" and push B and then S, or match nothing.
>   When we're in case B, match "b".

In all cases, we pop the current state from the stack.

### Writing the pattern in a .Net regular expression

We need to represent the different states somehow. We can't pick *'1' '2' '3'* or *'a' 'b' 'c'*, because those may not be available in our input string -  we can only match what is present in the string.
One option is to number our states (In the example above, `S` would state number 0, and `B` is state 1).
For state S we can push  characters to the stack. For convenience, we'll push the first  characters from the start of the string. Again, we don't care *what* are these characters, just how many there are.

#### Push state

In .Net, if we want to push the first 5 characters of a string to a stack, we can write:

```
(?<=(?=(?<StateId>.{5}))\A.*)
```

This is a little convoluted:

- `(?<=…\A.*)` is a lookbehind that goes all the way to the start of the string.
- When we're at the start there's a look ahead: `(?=…)`. This is done so we can match beyond the current position - if we are at position *2*, we don't have 5 characters before us. So we're looking back and looking forward.
- `(?<StateId>.{5})` push 5 characters to the stack, indicating that at some point we need to match state 5.

#### Pop state

According to our notation, we always pop the top state from the stack. That is easy: `(?<-StateId>)`.
But before we do that, we want to know what state that was - or how many characters it captured. More specifically, we need to check explicitly for each state, like a `switch`/`case` block. 
So, to check if the stack currently holds state 5:

```
(?<=(?=.{5}(?<=\A\k<StateId>))\A.*)
```

- Again, `(?<=…\A.*)` goes all the way to the start.
- Now we advance `(?=.{5}…)` by five characters...
- And use another lookbehind, `(?<=\A\k<StateId>)` to check that the stack really has 5 characters.

This has an obvious drawback - when the string is too short, we cannot represent the number of large states. This problem has solutions:

- The number of short words in the language is final anyway, so we can add them manually.
- Use something more complicated than a single stack - we can use several stacks, each with zero or one characters, effectively bits of our state (there's an example at the end).

### Result

Our pattern for a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> looks like this:

```
\A
# Push State A, Index = 0
(?<StateId>)
(?:
    (?:
        (?:
            # When In State A, Index = 0
            (?<=(?=.{0}(?<=\A\k<StateId>))\A.*)
            (?<-StateId>)
            (?:
                # Push State B, Index = 1
                (?<=(?=(?<StateId>.{1}))\A.*)
                a
                # Push State A, Index = 0
                (?<StateId>)
                |

            )
        )
        |
        (?:
            # When In State B, Index = 1
            (?<=(?=.{1}(?<=\A\k<StateId>))\A.*)
            (?<-StateId>)
            b
        )
        |\Z
    ){2}
)+
\Z
# Assert state stack is empty
(?(StateId)(?!))
```

**[Working example on Regex Storm](http://bit.ly/1bNozSN)**

#### Notes:

- Note that the quantifier around the states is `(?:(?:…){2})+` - that is, (state count)×(input length). I also added an alternation for `\Z`. Let's not get into that, but it's a workaround for an annoying optimization in the .Net engine.
- The same can be written as [`(?<A>a)+(?<-A>b)+(?(A)(?!))`](http://bit.ly/1hhVkNF) - this is just an exercise.

### To answer the question

The grammar from the question can be rewritten as:

```
# Start with <push A>
<pop A> -> <push A> ( @"," | <push Q> ) | ε
<pop Q> -> \w
           | "<" <push Q2Close> <push A>
           | "[" <push Q1Close> <push QStar> <push Q1Comma> <push QStar> <push Q1Semicolon> <push A>
<pop Q2Close> -> ">"
<pop QStar> -> <push QStar> <push Q> | ε 
<pop Q1Comma> -> ","?
<pop Q1Semicolon> -> ";"
<pop Q1Close> -> "]"
```

The pattern:

```
\A
# Push State A, Index = 0
(?<StateId>)
(?:
    (?:
        (?:
            # When In State A, Index = 0
            (?<=(?=.{0}(?<=\A\k<StateId>))\A.*)
            (?<-StateId>)
            (?:
                # Push State A, Index = 0
                (?<StateId>)
                (?:
                    ,
                    |
                    # Push State Q, Index = 1
                    (?<=(?=(?<StateId>.{1}))\A.*)
                )
                |

            )
        )
        |
        (?:
            # When In State Q, Index = 1
            (?<=(?=.{1}(?<=\A\k<StateId>))\A.*)
            (?<-StateId>)
            (?:
                \w
                |
                <
                # Push State Q2Close, Index = 2
                (?<=(?=(?<StateId>.{2}))\A.*)
                # Push State A, Index = 0
                (?<StateId>)
                |
                \[
                # Push State Q1Close, Index = 6
                (?<=(?=(?<StateId>.{6}))\A.*)
                # Push State QStar, Index = 3
                (?<=(?=(?<StateId>.{3}))\A.*)
                # Push State Q1Comma, Index = 4
                (?<=(?=(?<StateId>.{4}))\A.*)
                # Push State QStar, Index = 3
                (?<=(?=(?<StateId>.{3}))\A.*)
                # Push State Q1Semicolon, Index = 5
                (?<=(?=(?<StateId>.{5}))\A.*)
                # Push State A, Index = 0
                (?<StateId>)
            )
        )
        |
        (?:
            # When In State Q2Close, Index = 2
            (?<=(?=.{2}(?<=\A\k<StateId>))\A.*)
            (?<-StateId>)
            >
        )
        |
        (?:
            # When In State QStar, Index = 3
            (?<=(?=.{3}(?<=\A\k<StateId>))\A.*)
            (?<-StateId>)
            (?:
                # Push State QStar, Index = 3
                (?<=(?=(?<StateId>.{3}))\A.*)
                # Push State Q, Index = 1
                (?<=(?=(?<StateId>.{1}))\A.*)
                |

            )
        )
        |
        (?:
            # When In State Q1Comma, Index = 4
            (?<=(?=.{4}(?<=\A\k<StateId>))\A.*)
            (?<-StateId>)
            ,?
        )
        |
        (?:
            # When In State Q1Semicolon, Index = 5
            (?<=(?=.{5}(?<=\A\k<StateId>))\A.*)
            (?<-StateId>)
            ;
        )
        |
        (?:
            # When In State Q1Close, Index = 6
            (?<=(?=.{6}(?<=\A\k<StateId>))\A.*)
            (?<-StateId>)
            \]
        )
        |\Z
    ){7}
)+
\Z
# Assert state stack is empty
(?(StateId)(?!))
```

<sup>Sadly, it is too long to fit in a url, so no online example.</sup>

If we use "binary" stacks with one or zero characters, it would have looked like this: https://gist.github.com/kobi/8012361

Here's a screenshot of the pattern passing all tests: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW2xr.png

### Bonus

The .Net engine can do more than just to balance - it can also capture each instance of `A` or `Q`. This requires a slight modification of the pattern: https://gist.github.com/kobi/8156968 .
Note that we've added the groups *`Start`*, *`A`* and *`Q`* to the pattern, but they have no effect of the flow, they are used purely for capturing.

The result: for example, for the string `"[<a>b;<c,d>,<e,f>]"`, we can get these `Capture`s:

```
Group A
    (0-17) [<a>b;<c,d>,<e,f>]
    (1-4) <a>b
    (2-2) a
    (7-9) c,d
    (13-15) e,f
Group Q
    (0-17) [<a>b;<c,d>,<e,f>]
    (1-3) <a>
    (2-2) a
    (4-4) b
    (6-10) <c,d>
    (7-7) c
    (9-9) d
    (12-16) <e,f>
    (13-13) e
    (15-15) f
```

### Open questions

- Can every grammar be converted to the state-stack notation?
- Is (state count)×(input length) enough steps to match all words? What other formula can work?

### Source code

The code used to generate these patterns and all test cases can be found on https://github.com/kobi/RecreationalRegex

Answer (score 10):

The answer is <sub><sup>(probably)</sup></sub> Yes.

The technique is much more complex than the `(?1)` recursive call, but the result is  almost 1-to-1 with the rules of the grammar - I worked in a such methodical way I can easily see it scripted. Basically, you match block-by-block, and use the stack to keep track of where you are. This is an almost working solution:

```
^(?:
    (\w(?<Q>)) # Q1
    |
    (<(?<Angle>))  #Q2 - start <
    |
    (\>(?<-Angle>)(?<-A>)?(?<Q>))  #Q2 - end >, match Q
    |
    (\[(?<Block>))  # Q3 start - [
    |
    (;(?<Semi-Block>)(?<-A>)?)  #Q3 - ; after [
    |
    (\](?<-Semi>)(?<-Q>)*(?<Q>))  #Q3 ] after ;, match Q
    |
    ((,|(?<-Q>))*(?<A>))   #Match an A group
)*$
# Post Conditions
(?(Angle)(?!))
(?(Block)(?!))
(?(Semi)(?!))
```

It is missing the part of allowing commas in `Q->[A;Q*,?Q*]`, and for some reason allows `[A;A]`, so it matches `[;,,]` and `[abc;d,e,f]`. Rest of the strings match the same as the test cases.
Another minor point is an issue with pushing to the stack with an empty capture - it doesn't. `A` accepts Ø, so I had to use `(?<-A>)?` to check if it captured.

The whole regex [should look like this](http://gist.github.com/496062), but again, it is useless with the bug there.

#### Why it isn't working?

There is not way of synchronizing the stacks: if I push `(?<A>)` and `(?<B>)`, I can pop them in any order. That is why this pattern cannot differentiate `<z[a;b>]` from `<z[a;b]>`... we need one stack for all.
This [can be solved](http://kobikobi.wordpress.com/2010/12/14/net-regex-matching-mixed-balanced-parentheses/) for simple cases, but here we have something much more complicate - A whole `Q` or `A`, not just "<" or "[".

Comment: As a side note, I'm surprised I found so little material on the subject. I learned as I go, an it took a great deal of time. Anyway, if anyone finds the flaw in my code I'll be happy to hear.

Comment: This question still hunts me. I know my answer is fundamentally wrong, since it doesn't take order into account, similarly to http://kobikobi.wordpress.com/2010/12/14/net-regex-matching-mixed-balanced-parentheses/

Comment: If you don't mind, would you please answer this question with the solution in your blog? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502468/controlling-balanced-parenthesis

Comment: @nhahtdh - I am currently on vacation in Japan! Feel free to add or edit your answer  Thanks!