# Write a Regex to find all words in a string which are enclosed by brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match all the words in a string which have pattern like `{{word}}`

For Example:

This {{is}} a test {{String}}.
Should match **{{is}}** and **{{String}}**

I was using `/{{(.*?)}}/g` which gives correct result for above case but fails when I have string something like

This **{{is{{is}}}}** a test String

Output Should be: **{{is{{is}}}}** but it is returning **{{is{{is}}**

Comment: This is an issue of balancing groups which isn't easy to do with Javascript's flavor of regex. See, for example, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726770/how-to-match-balanced-delimiters-in-javascript-regex)

Comment: @9000 i thought js regex didn't support lookbehind. does it?

Comment: @Rico: Well, yes, I was wrong, removed my comment.

Answer (score 4):

One possible way is this.

```
{{[\w{}]+}}
```

Comment: You are making an assumption about what can be inside the braces (i.e. only word characters)

Comment: If we do not have this assumption, then regex can not be used here. Because regex in JavaScript does not support recursive. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414339/recursive-matching-with-regular-expressions-in-javascript

Comment: You could also use `\S` in place of `\w{}`, granted the `word` doesn't contain any spaces. This would allow for numbers and other symbols to be used.

Comment: `\w` allows digits. I agree we can use `\S` instead if we need to support other symbols.