# How to check if count of one part of the string is equal to another part with regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, validation

I have a strings like:

```
0011
01
000111
000111
```

I need to validate them like this: count of "0" must be identical to the count of "1". So "001" - invalid, "0011" - valid.

How can I do this with regex?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Check the answers of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644266/how-can-we-match-an-bn-with-java-regex

Comment: Or check the string against `/(0+)(1+)/` then compare the lengths of the captured sub-expressions.

Comment: Actually, the question mentioned does not have an example for Ruby.

Comment: @stribizhev Care to be more explicit about why those regexes won't work with Ruby's regex engine?

Comment: @muistooshort: In Ruby, the subroutines have different syntax that is rather misleading since it looks like a back-reference.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, you can use subroutines:

```
m = /\b(0(\g<1>)?1)\b/.match('000111');
puts m;
```

[Result of the demo](https://ideone.com/AdzDPs):

```
000111
```

Or, you can just use capturing groups to match adjacent `0`s and `1`s, and then check the captured group length:

```
m = /(0+)(1+)/.match('0011');
puts m[1].length === m[2].length ? "True" : "False";

m = /(0+)(1+)/.match('00111');
puts m[1].length === m[2].length ? "True" : "False";
```

You may add `^` and `$` to only match a string consisting of leading zeros and trailing `1`s (`m = /^(0+)(1+)$/.match('00111');`).

Output of the [demo program](https://ideone.com/HUEKxR):

```
True
False
```

Comment: It can be done if you adapt `'/ ^ (a (?1)? b) $ /x'` to Ruby: http://rubular.com/r/9JZfVgVosj

Comment: I have found out where I was wrong thanks to [rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html) I was just unaware of the `\g<1>` notation. Your suggestion - `^(?<k>a\g<k>?b)$` - is also working well, as I see.

Comment: Oh, `\g<1>` works. Rubular's error message is really misleading.