# Matching As followed by the same number of Bs in egrep

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep, pattern-matching

Suppose I want to match a pattern with the exact same number of characters A and B such that there are exactly n A's followed by exactly n B's.
For example, the following strings can be matched.

1. AB
2. AABB
3. AAABBB

On the other hand, these strings cannot be matched

1. BA
2. AAABB
3. AABBB
4. ABAB

To approach the problem, I am thinking about the repetition counts, so my attempt looks like this

```
egrep 'A{n}B{n}'
```

of course, however, the repetition count n inside the curly bracket cannot be defined implicitly.

While I know how to write programs to match it, I am testing this on Mac terminal,  hence I am trying to exploit any possible features of egrep to write the one sentence pattern.

So could anyone please help me solve this problem and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of [How can we match a^n b^n with Java regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3644266/7586). The broader answer is that regular expressions usually have trouble counting things.

Comment: Indeed, but the tricky part of this problem is that I have to run it on Unix, using egrep.

Comment: `egrep` alone won't be able to solve it. You need at least `gnu grep`. (see my answer below)

Answer (score 3):

If you have `gnu grep` then you can use this recursive PCRE regex:

```
grep -P '^(A(?1)?B)$' file

AB
AABB
AAABBB
```

Or else, you can use this non-regex approach using `awk`:

```
awk '(n=index($0, "B")) && length(substr($0, 1, n-1)) == length(substr($0, n))' file

AB
AABB
AAABBB
```

This `awk` find presence of first `B` using `index` function and extracts 2 substrings i.e all the `As` and all the `Bs` and prints each record if length of `As` substring is same length of `Bs` substring.

Answer (score 0):

Two alternative GNU **awk** approaches:

-- using `match` function:

```
awk '{ match($0,/^(A+)(B+)$/,a) }length(a) && length(a[1])==length(a[2])' file
```

---

-- using `FPAT` variable to define field value

```
awk -v FPAT="A|B" '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { ($i=="A" && $(i-1)!="B")? a++:b++ } }a==b' file
```

The output (for both approaches):

```
AB
AABB
AAABBB
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do this in `awk`, with your shown samples please try following `awk`. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work with any version of `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/^A+/){
  len=RLENGTH
  match(substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH),/^B+/)
  if(len==RLENGTH){ print }
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

if the lines *only* have A's and B's and nothing else, then here's an `awk`-based solution without needing to use `match()` function :

```
BBBBBBAAAAAAA
AAAABBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
AABBBB
BBAAA
AAAABBBB
AAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAABBBBBB
AAAABBB
BBAA
AAABBAABB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
AAABBB
AAAAABBBB
AAABB
AABB
AAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBB
BAA
AABBAABB
AAAAAABBBBBB
AAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAABBBBBB
AAABB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
ABAB
AAAAAAABBBB
AAAAAAABBBBBB
AAAAAABBBB
AAABB
AABB
AAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAABBBBBB
AB
AAAAABBBBBB
BBBBBBAAAAAA
AAB
AABBB
AAABBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAABBBBBB
AABAB
BA
```

|

```
 {m,g}awk '((_=length)%__)</^A+B+$/ && _==index($!__,"AB")*__' FS='^$' __=2

 1  AAAABBBB
 2  AAABBB
 3  AABB
 4  AAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBB
 5  AAAAAABBBBBB
 6  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
 7  AABB
 8  AB
 9  AAABBB
10  AAAAAABBBBBB
```

which can be quickly checked visually :

```
              AAAABBBB
               AAABBB
                AABB
      AAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBB
            AAAAAABBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
                AABB
                 AB
               AAABBB
            AAAAAABBBBBB
```