# How to create regex?

Tags: regex

Maybe somebody could help me, how to create regex, that will find two characters with the same amount one after another :

`ex. +++--- : true (3)
ex. ++++---- : true (4)
ex. ++--- : false (2 - 3)`

Thanks in forward

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we match a^n b^n with Java regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644266/how-can-we-match-an-bn-with-java-regex)

Comment: As you can see in the link above, it is in fact possible. But depending on the regex flavour you're using it may not be. JavaScript for example doesn't allow recursive patterns, nor balancing groups, plus having a particular behaviour on nested references, it won't match correctly for the given answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can match something like that in regex.

A workaround would be to split at boundaries between different characters with this regex:

```
(?<=(.))(?!\1)(?!$)
```

and see if the resulting array is:

- length = 2
- length of first element = length of second element

Comment: ok, i thought that it's impossible, but just wanted to be sure. Thanks a lot.