# Regex - Match 2 groups with same qualifier

Tags: regex

I would like to use regex to match following strings:

```
aba
ababaa
abababaaa
...
```

These strings follows the pattern :

```
(ab){1}(a){1}
(ab){2}(a}{2}
(ab){3}(a){3}
...
```

Is it possible to create a generic regex to much such pattern ( like `(ab){n}(a){n}` ) ?

Comment: What is the language or regex flavor?

Comment: See [How can we match a^n b^n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644266/) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o37srh/1).

Comment: Thanks, that's actually works! However it requires PCRE syntax support. Anyway i need it for my C++ program and boost::regex supports it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was posted by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew). Using PCRE syntax regex the solution is recursive pattern:

```
(ab(?1)?a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using quantifiers

```
(ab)+(a)+
```

`+` means 1 or more and `*` means 0 or more

Comment: The `(ab)+(a)+` pattern will also match `abaaaa`.

Comment: It shouldn't? I didn't get that from the question. Did you mean it should match 1 to 3 'a's in the end?

Comment: No. It should match exactly same number of 'a's at the end as 'ab's at beginning.

Comment: Oh. Then my answer is incorrect, sorry.